# How to run sql based on filter condition in Tableau report

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

I have this data output in Sql server for a table to which i have extracted in tableau using extract data :-

[image: SQL server output]

Requirement is that when user select source_nbr and stock_date which is under filter criteria in tableau dashboard, a sql query should fire which should bring the custom result from the extracted data in tableau and show it on tableau dashboard.

Query which will be fired based on user selection is :-

```
select top 1 with ties
   source_nbr,
   source_cc,
   stock_date,
   item_nbr,
   fin_rpt_grp_code,
   base_div_code,
   dept_nbr,
   item_desc,
   item_upc
from dbo.inventory_stock_status
WHERE source_nbr = <UserSelectedsource_nbr> and stock_date < <userSelectedDate> 
order by row_number() over (partition by item_nbr order by stock_date desc);
```

This is how my filtered column looks like in tableau workbook :-

[image: Example of selecting sourceNbr and stockDate in right side filter]

In a nutshell, when user selects source nbr and stock data on right side of tableau dashboard, above SQL should run behind the scene on extracted data and output data is shown to user.

Hope i made my question clear.

Comment: You will have a better experience with Tableau if you learn how its core features work and allow Tableau to generate SQL as needed - rather than trying to micromanage the SQL yourself. That's akin to trying to change the assembly code generated by your compiler -- useful in rare circumstances but in general an inefficient way to work

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cte as follows:

```
with table1 as
(
select
   source_nbr,
   source_cc,
   stock_date,
   item_nbr,
   fin_rpt_grp_code,
   base_div_code,
   dept_nbr,
   item_desc,
   item_upc,
   row_number() over (partition by item_nbr order by stock_date desc) as rn
from dbo.inventory_stock_status
WHERE source_nbr = <UserSelectedsource_nbr> and stock_date < <userSelectedDate>
)
select
   source_nbr,
   source_cc,
   stock_date,
   item_nbr,
   fin_rpt_grp_code,
   base_div_code,
   dept_nbr,
   item_desc,
   item_upc
from table1
order by rn
```

Comment: @MarkKram Thanks for pointing it out. Spell check does have surprises.

Comment: Teehee, it happens to the best of us. If it weren't for spell check and Google I would be in real trouble! 

Comment: @NeerajAgarwal How will i populate user selected date and sourceNbr into the sql query ? Where i need to configure this in tableau ?

Comment: @Neer1009 Those conditions are in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @NeerajAgarwal Probably i did not understand the answer completely. My question is how will i map the user selected data in tableau workbook  to sql query so that it can run the query with user provided input.

Comment: @Neer1009 User selected data in the WHERE clause that states WHERE source_nbr = <UserSelectedsource_nbr> and stock_date = <userSelectedDate>. UserSelectedsource_nbr and userSelectedDate are values selected by the user.

Comment: How to map user selected date under filter criteria in Tableau? I don't see any option in tableau to do this.

Comment: @Neer1009 Thanks for clarifying. I was just answering the SQL question. I am not able to help you with Tableau.